# Trouble with spellcasting classes and their save DCs in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting, witch

So I've played a caster in several Pathfinder games with my friends over the years, but I've continued to have the same problem with a lot of them. Namely, because of how save DCs work and how a lot of creatures are stated, it often feels pointless to use most spells on my list because FORT and WILL mods are always so high that I'd have to hope for 1 on the die half of the time. Even DEX saves can be remarkably high on an enemy's side so my only recourse is touch attacks or spells without DCs and even then I've dumped everything into my casting stat to even hope to make my save DC high enough to force a spell through.

The system is very content-dense, but so far I've only managed to find some small buffs like Spell Focus feats to bump up DCs. I think Arcanists have some exploits that can help too but I am currently playing a witch and my options feel rather limited. But it seems like there must be other options out there since so many people swear by casters' abilities and I know that to be true of this system and others, especially as I've seen other friends power game other builds. In particular, my friend's (current GM) previous oracle build was untouchably powerful. Is there just something that I am missing to make my caster viable? Able to land a spell on a creature with decent saves?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Would a good answer be, like, a list of of average monster saving throw bonuses at each level along with ways to reach appropriate save DCs, for instance? That is, what are imagining folks will tell you: "Take X class and Y race and Z, A, B, and C feats" or a general discussion of the game's underlying philosophy or both? No matter what, though, thank you for participating and for contributing an interesting question!

Comment: Can you add a few character details - int (including int-boosting items), level, and race, at least? And, is the GM mostly using monsters out of the monster manuals or are they custom-building most foes?

Comment: Are your GM building his own encounters, or if using published adventures, rising the CR to challenge more greatly your party? When monster advancement is done, the first thing to suffers is the DC of party spells and abilities. It seems the kind of scenario you are describing.